# Is there a support annotation to denote binding resources?

Tags: android, android-databinding

`@LayoutRes` denotes a layout resource (`R.layout.myLayout`), `@ColorRes` a color resource (`R.color.colorPrimary`), and so on. Is there any Android support annotation that denotes a binding resource (`BR.myVar`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data binding is a relatively new feature, and there is no specific annotation for its resources yet. However, you can use `@AnyRes` as a substitute for now.

See [annotation docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html):

> Use `@AnyRes` to indicate that the annotated parameter can be any type of R resource.

and [AnyRes docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/AnyRes.html):

> public interface AnyRes extends annotation.Annotation
>
> Denotes that an integer parameter, field or method return value is expected to be a resource reference of any type. If the specific type is known, use one of the more specific annotations instead, such as StringRes or DrawableRes.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know @AnyRes annotation. I'll use it for now. I'll accept in 5 minutes ;D